# Tenclone, twelveclone, Englishmen

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a short story from late 70's or so.

Two unrelated Englishmen who survived a famine (everyone went hungry, but nobody starved) in their youth live on a remote planet- I think a mining planet. A tenclone arrives (5 men, 5 women who know of the brilliant man they were cloned from), and is amused and dismissive of these geezers who are individuals.

The tenclone has an accident, 9 are killed. The one who survives must learn from the Englishmen how it is possible to love others as a way to escape the loneliness he now experiences. At the end the survivor leaves on the ship which is bringing in a twelveclone as a replacement.

Comment: The twelveclone bit, 'uh-huh, they do', prevented me from editing this.  Please expand on this, what a 'twelveclone' is exactly.

Comment: @Solemnity I think the OP is nudge-nudge-wink-winking about the (realized) potential for hanky panky in a mixed-sex group of clones.

Comment: This question does not have an accepted answer and **should be reopened**.

Comment: Hooray. It's reopened. Now we can...erm...leave it open forever.

Comment: Not a dupe unless OP confirms

Comment: They confirmed in a comment, see below.

Answer (score 10):

This reminds me a bit of Nine Lives by Ursula Le Guin. I can't find a copy, though I'm sure I have it in an anthology somewhere, but there is a brief summary [here](http://everythingisnice.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/nine-lives-by-ursula-k-leguin/). It's not an exact match to your description, but it's pretty close.

Comment: I'd be pretty sure it's "Nine Lives" -- a Google search for "twelveclone" turns up just this question and a page from "Nine Lives".

Comment: Definitely Nine Lives. Published in 1969. I have it in "The Wind's Twelve Quarters". The clones' 'parent' was named John Chow.

Comment: @Frock: aha, I have The Wind's Twelve Quarters hidden away somewhere. I'll dig it out and have a look. Thanks :-)

Comment: Same here. When I read the question, I immediately knew that I'd read the story; and this turned out to be it indeed. Shame it hasn't been accepted yet. The OP hasn't even been back to check.

Comment: Thank you all- I would have not thought of LeGuin although it does fit her well.

Comment: @user14607 it took you five years to see my answer? :-)

Comment: It did! I forgot about the story 'til just now.