# Two normal humans interact with a team of clones

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story I read in the 90s - I'd guess it's 20-30 pages long.

Two men are posted as scientific observers on an isolated planet for many years.  Despite their differences, they learn to get along and survive the solitude.  One day, a team of 12 identical clones arrives.  There are 6 males and 6 females who were cloned from a brilliant male biologist (by adding X chromosomes, etc.).  They are super close to each other; each one specializes in a different field of science, they all sleep together, and they don't really communicate well with outsiders.

The point of the story is the contrast between the original pair's way of dealing with differences and the clone's identical, in-built similarity which makes those skills unnecessary.

A disaster on the planet results in the death of some of the clones & explores the psychological aftermath of the breakup of their unit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Nine Lives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Lives_%28novelette%29) by Ursula K. LeGuin.  Posted in its entirety [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791405/9781625791405___2.htm).  And ISFDB info [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41107).   First published in Playboy magazine! *(I only looked at it for the sf stories)*.

> "It's a clone," Kaph said. "The other Exploit Team they're bringing with them."
> "Is it then?"
> "A twelveclone. They came out with us on the Passerine."

Comment: It is also published in Ursula's anthology [*The Wind's Twelve Quarters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind%27s_Twelve_Quarters). Woot!

Comment: Previously identified as the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/tenclone-twelveclone-englishmen/35676#35676)

Comment: @Lexible *The Wind's Twelve Quarters* is duly listed in the [ISFDB bibliography page](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41107) linked to in the answer.