# Looking for a pre-1975 short story about a space ship carrying male and female clones

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story of a science fiction collection set on a ship or freighter in space from the captain's point of view. He once refers to his second in command or pilot as "Little One".

The male and female clones (possibly 10 or more) of a single person come aboard. Even though genetically brothers and sisters (or twins), they have sex together and the captain wonders if he can approach one of the women.

Comment: This does sound very like *Nine Lives*. The captain would be Owen Pugh and his second in command is Lieutenant Martin, but he doesn't call Martin or anyone else "Little One" or anything like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reminiscent of the LeGuin story Nine Lives. You can read it at [baen.com](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781625791405/9781625791405___2.htm).

It definitely concerns a multiple clone that has sexual relations among themselves. But, it mostly takes place on a planet, not in a ship.

The publication date (1969) also matches.

It's also the accepted answer to this old question: [Two normal humans interact with a team of clones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86789/two-normal-humans-interact-with-a-team-of-clones)

Comment: I remember this story, there is a cave-in and some of the clones go further in, trying to get everyone out. At the end only one of the clones survives.

Comment: Nine Lives by Ursual Le Guin 1969 is the answer. Many thanks @organicmarble and johnrennie