# Short story from a '70s/'80s Playboy anthology, involving a boy/man who finds himself in a time loop

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Maybe 40-50 years ago, there was a story in a *Playboy* anthology, with a white cover, of a man who awoke and found he was 12 years old (?) again, but had all his memories.  He almost immediately used his knowledge and his boy scout knife to put the fear of god into his older brother, who the first time around picked on him a lot.

Comment: I only ever read Playboy for the SF stories.

Comment: Possibly this anthology http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?45400

Comment: You and me both, @Moriarty https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86794/28516

Comment: @Andrew That appears to be the _only_ anthology of Playboy-published SF released in the suggested timeframe.

Comment: @Chase51 I went through *The Playboy Book of Science Fiction and Fantasy* (1966), which seems to be their only SF collection published before the end of the 1980s, and there aren't any matching stories in it.

Comment: I also checked my copies of PBoSFaF and the similar Playboy horror, crime, and humor anthologies, without success. However, this question did make me want to read through those books again, so +1.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of a long shot, but since I didn't find a story at all like this in *The Playboy Book of Science Fiction and Fantasy* (1966), which is the only anthology of SF published in *Playboy* I can find before 1990, it's possible that other details are confused as well.

The immediate story I think of when a man is thrown back into his boyhood body with his adult memories is "[Time and Time Again](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45674)" (1947) by H. Beam Piper.  The boy is thirteen, not twelve, and his first attempt to change history is to prevent a neighbour from killing his wife.  You can read the entire story [at Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.org/files/18831/18831-h/18831-h.htm).

The story famously ends with the line "when you grow up, I'll be president.... Let's go get supper, now."

Comment: Query: use of the term "famously"? Is this a term that has been used elsewhere? Certainly "you'll grow up to be president", but this particular version I have not heard.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Well this is, at least in my experience, a rather well-known inversion of the standard saying; I think I've even heard it repurposed to other (time-travel related) contexts.