# 1960s era science fiction short story where a boy wakes up with knowledge he had as an adult

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A man wakes up as the boy he was with all the knowledge he had as an adult.  His old brother who picks on him gets surprised and decked with boy holding boy scout knife to brother's throat and threatening him successfully.  Drinking, investing, ladies and more.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like H. Beam Piper's "[Time and Time Again](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45674)" (1947).  A man (Allan Hartley) is killed in a nuclear attack during World War III in Buffalo and wakes up in his childhood home as a thirteen-year-old, but with all his memories of his life after that time.

With his knowledge of future events he first changes history by removing the firing pin of a gun his father is lending a neighbour ostensibly to shoot his dog.  Allan remembers that he doesn't have a dog and used the gun to shoot his wife, so he calls the police to have him arrested.

Knowing he *can* change history, Allan (with help from his father Blake) set out to change history to prevent WWIII from happening.  Investing and gambling figure prominently in their plan to raise money in order to gain influence.

> "Unlimited wealth and influence. Here." Allan picked up a sheet and handed it to his father. "Used properly, we can make two or three million on that, alone. A list of all the Kentucky Derby, Preakness, and Belmont winners to 1970. That'll furnish us primary capital. Then, remember, I was something of a chemist. I took it up, originally, to get background material for one of my detective stories; it fascinated me, and I made it a hobby, and then a source of income. I'm thirty years ahead of any chemist in the world, now. You remember *I.G. Farbenindustrie*? Ten years from now, we'll make them look like pikers."

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266526/short-story-from-a-70s-80s-playboy-anthology-involving-a-boy-man-who-finds-hi/266537#266537

Comment: No older brother, no threatening with a knife, and no drinking, but yeah, that's the one that pops into my mind as well. The link includes a PG copy to mine quotes from.

Comment: I think you should be adding the next bit after that quote about the plans he has for his father.  The money and influence are merely the means to an end