# Short story about clone repair team where one dies

Tags: story-identification, clones

I remember reading a short story in high school that was about a team of engineers or mechanics that were all clones, I think 3 men and 3 women, that were assigned to repair something on an outpost. During the mission one of them gets killed, and the story is about how the rest kind of fall apart. Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: Fall apart emotionally? Or, like, disintegrate?  When were you in high school?

Comment: fall apart emotionally. I was in Denver

Comment: I think Nine Lives might be it. WIll check it out, Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Well the details don't quite match but it could be [Nine Lives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Lives_(novelette)) by Ursula K. Le Guin. I no longer have the book with that story. The synopsis I wrote for myself says:

Two men are doing asteroid mining. A nine-member clone (some male and some female) are sent to work with them. The clone is/are so similar that they work very well together.

> In a mining accident, all but one are killed. The survivor does not know how to cope.

Comment: Nine Lives has been asked about a few times here.  Check out https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/looking-for-a-pre-1975-short-story-about-a-space-ship-carrying-male-and-female-c/187875#187875, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86789/two-normal-humans-interact-with-a-team-of-clones/86794#86794, and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/tenclone-twelveclone-englishmen/35676#35676